# .NET Application domains and ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, appdomain

We all know that the .NET architecture introduced the concept of **application domains**.
ASP.NET creates an application domain for each Web application that runs on a Web server.
With a *process viewer*, you will not see the process for individual web applications executing because there's no new process created for them.

How can I view the individual web applications statistics such as:

- CPU usage,
- memory usage   and any other statistics that you can normally view using a process viewer?

Answer (score 1):

perfmon is fine but will not tell you which app pools the processes relate to if you run `c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe c:\windows\system32\iisapp.vbs` this will show you the PIDs and app pool names.